# Scip Branch and bound Pruning via bounds

Tags: python, package, mixed-integer-programming, scip

In using the SCIP library I was wondering how exactly pruning is done with respect to the bounds.
If we consider a minimization problem we can instantiate by computing a lower bound via LP-relaxation and upper bound via a greedy algorithm. Then after branching and computing LP-relaxations, we can confidently prune away portions that are worse than the greedy algorithm. But how exactly is this instantiating done in SCIP? Given an arbitrary MIP how does it identify the initial lower-bound.

I've looked into the documentation but can't really find anything with confidence

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't really understand the question: you already wrote the lower bound comes from the LP relaxation. Do you mean upper bound? That is either found by heuristics (SCIP has a lot of them) or later on by an integral LP solution